# Android Studio 4.2 - Kotlin version 1.5.0 error and endless loading for suggestions in Project Structure window

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-4.2

And what does it mean?

[image]

[image]

I tried to change `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0-release-764'`
but in this case gradle project fails to build with `Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.`

**UPDATE** `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'` - also doesn't work, same error and warning

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'

    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to
> adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.

**UPDATE 2**

I had to add `mavenCentral()` to make it work, though warning is still there but it builds

Also another issue if 4.2 version is endless loading for suggestions in Project Structure window after you updated version of one dependency

[image]

Comment: Same problem!!!

Comment: To me the only change was to change `1.5.0-release-764` with `1.5.0` and it worked. `Android Studio 4.2 Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7322048, built on April 29, 2021`. I created a file -> new project "empty activity project" template. Min API 29.

Comment: Adding mavenCentral worked for me for most the issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They released new version `202-1.5.10-release-894-AS8194.7`

Now it works fine without any warning with: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'`

Though I didn't check the second issue

> endless loading for suggestions in Project Structure window

Comment: 1.5.10 did nto work for me, I had to use 1.5.0

Comment: @BrillPappin update Kotlin plugin in Android Studio!

Comment: We ended up having to downgrade. We were having too many problems with dependencies,and it just wasn't worth time it was costing us to figure it out.I think we're going to have to wait for the plugins, and other components, to catch up.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently with version `1.5.10-release-894`.
So I change to `1.5.10` and now it builds !

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Also I updated the build.gradle to version `4.2.1`

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try with " :

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: what? are you serious?

Comment: yes sadly there is little bug that changes the location of the new update file in server side. btw did it worked ?

Comment: I mean you can't be serious? it has nothing to do with single or double quotes, of course nothing changes